# Oracle Timestamp: extract full hour

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I need to extract the 'full' hour of a timestamp. Like for 2010.03.04 13:13 I want 2010.03.04 13:00 (as a timestamp again).

My current approach is:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(m.begin, 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24')
```

Is this really the way to go? Who good/bad does it perform (I plan to do a GROUP BY on it).

Thanks for your input!

Cheers,
Reto

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  TRUNC(m.begin, 'HH24')
FROM    mytable m
```

Comment: Here is official docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TRUNC() function:

http://www.psoug.org/reference/date_func.html